# Webform permissions

Tags: webforms

Is there any possibility to give permissions to a role that can only download or manage the results or submissions to do through webforms and that this option appears in the admin bar of drupal?

Currently I use the webform module (6.2.0-rc3) and Admintoolbar (3.4.2) and I have not been able to find the permissions that allow me to do this.

Comment: I do not understand the question.

Comment: @cilefen Basically I need to give a role the permission to download only the results or submissions of the forms created in webform and that this will appear in the administration bar.

Comment: That is two questions.